# How do you show words surrounded by angle-brackets (< >)?

Tags: support, markdown, markdown-rendering

Because of the Stack Overflow's Markdown editing system, I can't find a way to show words surrounded by angle brackets (< >). When text is placed inside these brackets, it is thought to be a link and is hidden.  In certain situations, I would like to show words or blocks of text in this way.

Such as when an error has  "<.Bad Ptr>"

I wish to show this message *without* the period.

I know one way is to add a period or space after the first open bracket, as I did above.  Is there another way around this?

Comment: How did you manage it in this post?? Also for code formatting it will be supported out of the box.

Comment: @rene <.Bad Ptr> is part of an error message not code.  I managed it in the post by using a period.

Comment: You can use code formatting for error messages, so you don't need to additionally edit them.

Comment: Related: [Please block posts containing unsupported HTML](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300679/please-block-posts-containing-unsupported-html)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Either use HTML entities such as `&lt;` and `&gt;`, or use backticks (`` ` ``) to mark up the section as *code*.

Demo:

- Using HTML escapes, `&lt;Bad Ptr&gt;` is rendered as:

  > <Bad Ptr>
- Using backticks, `` `<Bad Ptr>` `` is rendered as:

  > `<Bad Ptr>`

Since you are talking about an error message here, I'd go with the backticks here.

Answer (score 9):

HTML encode the characters:

> <>

is

> `&lt;&gt;`

Comment: No need to encode the greater than symbol. Side note, <you don't have to worry about this at all in comments>.