# Please block posts containing unsupported HTML

Tags: feature-request, markdown, markdown-rendering, quality-filter, quality-improvement

Having had a look at [Things in <angle brackets> that aren't HTML should not disappear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300664), where jtbandes publicises his irritation with silently-disappearing code, got me to thinking:

**Please block posts containing html-tags which SE's markdown implementation does not accept.**
That *should* severely cut down on the number of posts which contain HTML/PHP code-samples and Java/C#/C++ generics/template-arguments which are silently ignored.

The error-message should be something like:

> Posts can only contain [a restricted subset of HTML](/editing-help#html), though prefer markdown where possible. If it should be code instead, [mark it as code](/editing-help#code). If you really want the `<` symbol, that's `&lt;`.

Comment: alternatively, such posts could be redirected to [meta-tag:triage]

Comment: I don't see the use in letting them through the gate. Though it having been blocked from submission at least once *might* be used as an input to the algorithm feeding triage.

Comment: agree, I suggested triage as alternative only for the case if SE team feels reluctant to add yet another heuristics to [meta-tag:quality-filter]. If they hesitate to outright block such questions, they could at least make them stop polluting site / tag pages

Comment: I'm split on this. I can't help but thinking that some users, when confronted to this message and the impossibility to post their question, will simply *remove the offending material completely*, therefore making their question both unanswerable and unsalvageable by editors.

Comment: Maybe it needs a giant arrow that bobs back and forth, pointing at the preview while flashing the words "Look here!".

Comment: "Speaking out instead of suffering silently"...wait, this isn't a rant about downvotes being unfair and you will not tolerate it any more *<ragequit>*???

Comment: This would invalidate [this recently posted answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300573/4639281).

Comment: @TinyGiant: Only if for some reason SE decided that comments are not a supported tag. That's unlikely though.

Comment: @Deduplicator, SE removes comments from the markdown before converting to HTML because it is lumped in with the unsupported tags. Look at the HTML source of that answer to see. If this affected all tags that are currently removed from posts (i.e. unsupported) then it definitely would.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I don't see how that implementation-detail has any bearing on things.

Comment: "*Please block posts containing html-tags which SE's markdown implementation does not accept.*" SE's markdown implementation does not accept comments, so if I tried to submit an answer with code blocks separated by a comment then it would block my post. All I'm saying is that your assertion is slightly naive.

Comment: @TinyGiant that is a separate issue. If the demand for successive code blocks without any visible text or lines in between is that high, something else can be found to realize that. I wouldn't know though why you couldn't post a little text in between, like "JavaScript:", or rather, an explanation of what the following code block does.

Comment: @CodeCaster HTML comments are also the only way to [override the default syntax highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

Comment: Yeah, so those tags are valid and recognized, so using them in a post won't get them removed or your post blocked even if this proposal were to be implemented... OP's post explicitly mentions _"which SE's markdown implementation does not accept"_. Not sure what you're getting at here.

Comment: These mistakes are easily fixed by editors and/or the triage process, i'd just let them through as we do now.

Comment: @KevinB: There are multiple possibilities: 1. It's unsupported formatting, so it's either benign or needs reformatting. 2. It's mis-formatted code, and thus easily fixed *if recognized*. 3. It should have been simple uses of < and >, which confuses either the poster (who doesn't understand why SO is hostile to innocent angle-brackets and declines showing them), or the readers because *something is missing*, though maybe not bad enough to guess at the cause.

Comment: I just want to say it's not the UNsupported tags that are the problem here, it's the supported ones! Too many times I have seen messages where the source reads `the problem is with your <p> element...` and the resulting post is utterly confusing!

Comment: @MrLister: That's common? Anyway, as I have no idea how to determine whether an allowed tag should have been inline-code, I haven't posted a feature-request for it...

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes, it's common. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33519647/1016716), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32301860/1016716), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32339483/1016716), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32310275/1016716), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32880126/1016716), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32903991/1016716), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33844995/1016716), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33119562/1016716), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33849449/1016716), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33847504/1016716), etc.

Comment: (I wanted to go on, but I ran out of comment space).

Comment: @MrLister: Well, I still don't have any idea for automatically handling that, aside from disallowing *all* html. And that would be somewhat sub-optimal, because sometimes (rarely), html is useful and there's no markdown equivalent.

Answer (score 55):

There are basically three ways to perform rich text markup of posts on the web: HTML, [BBCode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode) and [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), with or without a WYSI(NQ)WYG GUI. For developers, who work with text all day, using either of those markup languages should not be any problem, especially when you get a nice auto-updating preview of your post below your text area.

I don't know why half of the posts I encounter have formatting errors. There's people who use backticks (``) for entire code blocks (should be used for `inline code` only), users posting code in `<pre></pre>` tags (no highlighting), users not indenting their code at all (so the first and last line are seen as text), and so on.

I'm curious why posts looking like that get posted. Like the poster doesn't care, or doesn't see, what their post looks like. It is not that hard to look twice at what you're about to post. I'm all for blocking posts that are malformed.

We already have warnings in place for posts that seem to be code-only. Adding a blockage for people who don't know how to indent a block of HTML sounds about fair.

As for [Frédéric's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300679/speaking-out-instead-of-suffering-silently#comment228144_300679), paraphrasing *"This might cause posters to remove the offending code from their post altogether, making the question unsalvageable"*: good. The faster questions with that little effort spent on them are moved to trash, the better.

Comment: "WYSI(NQ)WYG GUI" does the "NQ" mean "not quite"?

Comment: @ryan yes, it does. I'm not talking about StackExchange specifically in that sentence, though the live preview does differ sometimes from what you see after posting.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph. Close them with a burning passion!

Comment: Half of the posts you encounter have formatting errors even though the markdown is explained nearby and the post is previewed below because [everybody knows that users don't read manuals](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/fog0000000249.html).

Comment: @Jashaszun just because someone is new to the site and doesn't know the formatting rules, doesn't necessarily mean it will be a bad question. You might *think* so having judged such questions in the past, since a large proportion of them will be bad questions - but the same is true of questions without any formatting problems too. The vast majority of new questions are just bad.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: I saw your link but I didn't read it.

Comment: In my experience I find the way in which code formatting is done quite awkward. Pasting from source often ends up with most of it formatted automatically (because the tabs are being pasted along with it). Except for the first line, of course. Editing code often causes it to lose the formatting markup (particularly if deleting lines). The only way to guarantee that blocks of code will be considered such is to highlight the entire lot and nuke the site from orbit. And using the tab button of course moves you to the tag section of a question. AAAAAHHH.

Comment: half of the posts   have formatting errors probably because of ineffective "Post Question" GUI. After clicking "Post the question" button, it should bring up the preview (without the edit area) and have two buttons there - "Are You Sure" and "Back to Editing". (Like they have in WP's visual editing.)

Comment: @Stumbler to post code, paste it in your favorite editor, Shift+Tab the whole shebang to the left, then Tab once and post it. It's sad you need an external editor, but it works way better this way.

Comment: @CodeCaster that's what I do do... when I remember to.

Comment: Poorly formatted questions become unsalvagable? [Good](http://www.asicentral.com/images/blogs/grumpy-good.jpg)!

Comment: @Siguza sorry if I sounded like a grumpy old cat. Posts that don't look good hardly are interesting though.

Comment: @CodeCaster No, I'm the grumpy cat here. ^^ And I actually find poorly formatted questions offending, because it shows how the asker has put no effort into their question whatsoever.

Comment: @Stumbler And that's precisely why tabs suck: They're not web-compatible. Besides the fact that they have no fixed with, of course, and everyone using them as if they were 4 spaces wide, when every default setting I've ever seen only renders them 2, 8 or 12 spaces wide. -.-

Comment: No shame over being grumpy about people who can't get their question presentable. (I'd be *very* surprised if there's no correlation between poor formatting and poor content.) May I suggest including grumpy cat in your post? I believe that would be a small improvement. ;) I would also suggesting replacing "those" to "questions with that little effort" in the last sentence. Because someone thinking it's better to include *no* code than to format it properly is a clear indicator that they're not going to put much effort in (which is what I'm pretty sure you meant to imply).

Comment: @CodeCaster downvotes are likely from rep whores who [jump at every question](http://i.stack.imgur.com/V72GW.png), no matter how bad and drop their garbage answers over there. What you suggest means less stuff for them to vomit their "help" to, no wonder that they are unhappy

Answer (score 8):

I agree that this is a problem.  What's most annoying is that this would be fairly trivial for SE to fix — there's a specific piece of code in the Markdown sanitizer that replaces unrecognized HTML-tag-like things with an empty string, and it should not be hard to make it trigger a warning when the post is being submitted.

Still, while waiting for an official fix, I've added a client-side implementation of this feature to the [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) user script.  (It's currently in the v1.35 development branch; if no unexpected problems arise, it should be part of the v1.36 stable release in a few weeks at most.)

Here's a screenshot showing it in action:

[image: Screenshot]

The message reads:

> Your post appears to contain HTML tags that are malformed, mismatched or [not permitted in posts](/editing-help#html), and which will be silently removed. Where possible, please use Markdown syntax instead of HTML. To enter code that contains the `<` symbol, please use [proper code formatting](/editing-help#code) (or write it as `&lt;`).

To (hopefully) keep the warning message from being triggered too often while you're halfway through typing a tag, it's only shown when you either click outside the edit box or stop typing for three seconds.  You can dismiss the warning box by clicking it; if dismissed, it will stay hidden until you fix all HTML errors in the post, after which it will reappear if you add any new errors.  (This last bit was sort of accidental, but I've kept it for now, since it seems to work reasonably well.  Suggestions for a better UX are welcome.)

The way I detect when to show the popup is by setting up a custom Markdown converter hook that runs during the preview process, just before the normal SE HTML sanitization code.  In the hook, I run the same sanitization code (conveniently exposed via the `sanitizeHtml()` and `balanceTags()` methods of `StackExchange.MarkdownEditor`) on a copy of the post content, and check if the output differs from the input.  (To avoid false positives, I first preprocess the copy to strip any HTML comments and to replace link and image URLs with dummy placeholders.)  If it does, I set a flag and start a timer to display the warning.

The warning does *not* stop the post from being submitted, so even if it *does* somehow get triggered by mistake, it should be safe to ignore.  (That said, please do let me know if that happens.)  I'm not sure if I should add some kind of a confirmation step if you submit the post while the warning is still pending; hopefully, the two-second delay is short enough to make that unlikely.

Comment: Nice one, though if it ever gets implemented officially I really want a hard error there. Also, unfortunately those who would most benefit from it are extremely unlikely to have any customizations for SO at all.

Answer (score 4):

It will be nice to have a way to post the output of a program. Many times I use:

```
<!-- language : lang-none -->

    Output line 1
    Output line 2
    etc.
```

to post output of a program.

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> we are able to create a block of text that is treated as code.

Can there be a similar keyboard shortcut to create a block of text that is treated as output of a program? That might help reduce the problem of spurious HTML markup like text in a post.

Comment: While we are being pedants, can you make it `Ctrl` too? `<kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>` :)