# What is sign `<` while posting

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, markdown, posting

I noticed I can't use sign `<` while posting.

It happened when I tried to write this text

```
Dictionary<string, int>
```

but in preview it was shown as

```
Dictionary
```

Obviously currently these are written as code (with 4 spaces)

But if you write it in plain text it does not show the part `<string, int>`.

What is the reason? is there any special syntax for `<` that hides the text?

Example right here. see inside edit!

Comment: You probably use `pre` tag, means you can use html tags and a html tag starts with `<`

Comment: You *can* use < in plain text; just substitute with `&lt;`

Comment: Use backticks for inline code, `like this`: \`like this\`

Comment: Related feature-request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300679/speaking-out-instead-of-suffering-silently

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing special, just HTML.

Any HTML markup (in the whitelist) is **gonna be rendered as the HTML:**

```
Any HTML markup is <strong>gonna be rendered as the HTML</strong>
```

If it's not in the whitelist, like `<string, int>`, it's not gonna show it.

It has an open  and a close tag, pretty much all it looks for, so you can't see this:

Unless you view the revision history.

You may ask, why not only treat it as HTML if it sees a close tag too? Well:

```
<br>
```

doesn't need a close tag.

Comment: well i wish it was only hidden when tag is understood by stackoverflow. currently `<string, int>` does not make sense in html. anyways thanks for the answer

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I think this is standard html...

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Markdown can pass the angle bracketed text through unaltered (depending on how it is configured). However, the browser will never show it. That is standard browser behavior. In fact, in some cases, the browser could choke on this (usually older versions) as it sees this an invalid HTML. If you want to include anything in angle brackets, you need to mark it as code (which it is): `\`Dictionary<string, int>\`` which will get rendered as `<code>Dictionary&lt;string, int&gt;</code>` and will display in any browser correctly.

Comment: "Any HTML markup is gonna be rendered as the HTML" -- not exactly. The markdown parser *sanitizes* what it *thinks* is HTML (it's not too smart, just looks for angle brackets). If the markdown parser thinks it's HTML and it's not [a whitelisted "tag"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/237685), the parser removes the "tag".

Comment: @hichris123 I've edited, feel free to improve upon it.