# Why was this edit rejected as "deviates from original intent"?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I proposed this edit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9440978

It included a couple of (minor) phrase changes, which are a matter of opinion, and I'm not posting about those. The primary purpose of the edit was to format the code. The example code in the original post included this line:

```
<p:messages id="CusMessage"/>
```

It was not indented as a code block, so it was rendered as an HTML `<p>` tag in the output (in other words, to someone not looking at the Markdown source, it was invisible).

I wonder if the reviewers looked at the rendered diff and thought I added a line of code (which I understand is generally considered bad form), and did not review the Markdown, which would have readily shown the original poster's formatting mistake.

Comment: I think you're wondering correctly. It's always a good idea to include a descriptive reason for the suggested edit - even more so when it's not obvious to the reviewers that encounter edits like this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I resubmitted the edit with a better description.

Comment: Yeah - I prooobably would have accepted this edit because hey, "formatting", that's what it is. Every so often I find edits where the summary *does not match the content of the edit at all* (usually the placeholder "improved formatting" or some misspelling thereof). I wish it were OK to reject edits solely for not including a proper edit summary.

Comment: @BoltClock If you see the suggested edit in the "rendered output" view, that is not immediately clear. It looks like some (irrelevant?) markup was **added** to the question, not just that some formatting was changed (although, yes, that is what is actually done). I'd really love it if SO would make these types of changes more clear (or default to the markdown view).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That's the thing though, as a reviewer you should be expected to look at the markdown if an edit isn't immediately clear. You gotta be thorough.

Comment: @JonClements I think some kind of pop up warning should be triggered if "formatting" is entered as the only description for an edit. We get way too many edits that are labeled "formatting" that consist of anything from a tag being removed/added to a partial rewrite of OP's code in the question.

Comment: @ElGavilan I think in this case the burden should be on the editor, not on the reviewer. It **clearly** looks like something unnecessarily was added (together with formatting changes(!) covered by the edit comment), so reject appears to be the right course of action. Funny thing though: usually people complain about trigger happy approvers, but when the reverse happens, people yet again complain.

Comment: I actually never realized that the side-by-side was a comparison of the rendered output, and not the markdown. Obviously when looking at the markdown the edit makes sense, but I would probably not have seen it... I feel a little stupid

Comment: Sort of related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300679/speaking-out-instead-of-suffering-silently

Comment: In case anyone is interested to vote/discuss, I posted a feature request on this subject: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305690/warn-if-a-post-includes-html-tag-outside-a-code-block

Comment: Maybe a solution is to allow the editor to press a radio button for default review view (rendered vs. markdown).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When making an edit like that, where you find code that was hidden by poor formatting, the comment `formatting` probably won't do it.

Reviewers are pretty lax, but they are also lazy.  They sometimes glance, see massive changes without justification, and reject.

Make the reviewers job easy.  Say "Original post had hidden code due to a formatting error. Indented code, and it now appears properly." or some such that highlights why your edit is a valid one.

Even doing this won't always work. But it should give better results.

Comment: I absolutely see what you're saying, but will mention that in this situation it wasn't until after I submitted the edit that I actually realized there was a "hidden text" problem here.

Comment: @DanLowe The issue isn't culpability.  There is no culpability in this case (unless it is the stack overflow review system).  There is only why it happened, and what to do going forward.

Comment: I know that, all I'm saying is that once an edit is submitted there's no way to change the summary text (AFAIK), so I was stuck with the summary I had already written.

Comment: @DanLowe There is a way - if you edit again inside 5 minutes grace period, later summary will replace earlier. For sure works for edits, don't know about edit *suggestions*.

Comment: @Mołot: For suggestions, it's both better and worse. *Any time before the suggestion is approved* counts as the grace period. As soon as it's approved, and no sooner or later, the grace period ends.