# How to enter left angle bracket in stackoverflow inquiry

Tags: discussion

How can I enter left angle brackets in a stack overflow question?  I need this for things like HTML tags and jquery things.  When I include the left angle bracket, stackoverflow's code-behind makes a mishmash of everything following.

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300679/please-block-posts-containing-unsupported-html) might have helped you figure it out, if it was implemented...

Answer (score 5):

If you need to show html code like

```
<html>
    <body>html</body>
</html>
```

You can do with 2 methods.
First, prefix each line of your code with 4 white space.
Second, after write your code select all your code and press key Ctrl+K.

But if you need to show < in your questiong (not html code) use

```
&lt; for <
&gt; for >
```

[image]

Comment: You can also add a space directly after the < , which is faster when you need it out of code.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, ask these queries on meta.

And for html code, add 4 spaces before your html code.

for ex:
{4 spaces} {html code}

```
<html>
```