# List followed by a code block

Tags: support, code-formatting

How can I have a code block after a list? It seems ok if there is some text between the two, otherwise the indent is not being correctly parsed.

A list:

1. weeeeeee
2. blah
3. wooooot

A code block:

```
<div>:o</div>
<div>:(</div>
```

The same list directly followed by the code block:

1. weeeeeee
2. blah
3. wooooot

   :o

   :(

The same list followed by several blank lines and then the code block:

1. weeeeeee
2. blah
3. wooooot

   :o

   :(

Ref this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33447179/1301076 I ended up having to use 1) 2) 3) instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to accomplish this you can

1. First start listing your normal list items
2. With the syntax of `X. text`
3. And then when we are done with the list end it with a `<!-- -->`

```
and now we can have our code block
```

The source for this formatting is

```
In order to accomplish this you can

 1. First start listing your normal list items
 2. With the syntax of ` X. text`
 3. And then when we are done with the list end it with a `<!-- -->`

<!-- -->

    and now we can have our code block
```

Comment: I've had success using  `<?-------------->` to create a break between the list and the code element.

Comment: `<!>` `<!-->` `<!-- -->` The latter is recommended because it is an actual HTML comment, but all of those work.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Unfortunately, any and all of those work to break the flow. I have a FR to tighten that: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300679/please-block-posts-containing-unsupported-html

Comment: @TinyGiant: Yes, they all work. Though only the last *should* work.

Comment: @Deduplicator: and thereby break existing "code" ;). Ah well, I suppose I should learn the rudiments of basic HTML.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: The breakage would only occur on re-rendering due to edits, and it should be easy enough to clean up the source automatically anyway... I think the advantage is well worth it.

Comment: @Deduplicator: yes, I don't truly disagree but am more making fun of my attempts HTML pseudo-comments.