# Have the properties of quoted > text blocks changed?

Tags: support, code-formatting

Recently I found a lot of posts with quoted text blocks that contained html style (< > delimited) tags, which were not visible on the screen, because they were treated as actual HTML tags and discarded.

One example is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33493236/1016716), that contained the text

`> Valid values for <version> are ...`

which came out as

> Valid values for  are ...

(I've edited the question since, so you'll have to look in the edit history for the original.)

Now at first I thought that those posts were made by inexperienced SO users who didn't know any better, so I edited the posts to make the words visible and thought nothing of it.
However, the above post was written by a very experienced SO user, who *should* know better.

Therefore my question is, were those quote blocks treated differently before? Could you paste < and stuff in without it being swallowed up?

Comment: No, markup ever tried to interpret HTML tags.

Comment: Probably just a copy-paste oversight.

Comment: [Please block posts containing unsupported HTML](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300679/please-block-posts-containing-unsupported-html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The poster simply made a mistake.

As a side note, you should use code formatting instead of encoding the HTML entities, when it is actual code, so

> Valid values for `<version>` are 1.7 or 7 for OpenJDK 7 and 1.8 or 8 for Oracle JDK 8.

instead of

> Valid values for <version> are 1.7 or 7 for OpenJDK 7 and 1.8 or 8 for Oracle JDK 8.

Comment: Which is why I proposed http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300679/please-block-posts-containing-unsupported-html

Comment: @Deduplicator: from an answer there: "It is not that hard to look twice at what you're about to post. I'm all for blocking posts that are malformed." What a nasty surprise that should be for this particular answerer :D

Comment: WRT your side note: you're right, that would even have been closer to the original that the quote was quoted from. Not going to edit that post again though...