# Why are <> tags not allowed in the body?

Tags: support, markdown

I have noticed that when type tags with `<>` they are deleted on the final body. Why is that a thing? URL purposes? Flood?

Comment: These are interpreted as (unknown) HTML tags by the markup renderer, just escape these using the inline code backticks, or use code formatting. Also you should give a sample here.

Comment: [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and [Allowed html tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites/135909#135909)

Comment: Thanks! By the way, I can't give a sample, because like I said you can't do it.

Comment: html entities.. (doesn't work in comments tho)

Comment: @KevinB comments don't interpret html, so it's <safe>

Comment: Also see: [Please block posts containing unsupported HTML](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300679/please-block-posts-containing-unsupported-html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use < and > if you want; however, the Markdown used here supports [a subset of HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites). When you enclose text in < and >, it gets interpreted as an html tag and, since it's likely not a recognized tag, it ends up effectively being removed.
If you want it to show up in your post, either put it in `` inline code by using backticks: `<>` ``

```
or in a code block by indenting: <>
```

or type &lt; and &gt;  which will be rendered as < and >

You can find more information on formatting your posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

I also find it very helpful to look at the revision history of other people's posts, which can help you learn how to correctly format your own. For example, you can see the markdown of my answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/3270fcbe-36a3-4c40-8a44-4b5a567e640b/view-source), or by clicking the "edited on XXXX" link at the bottom. On the main site, you can also click on "edit" to see the raw text of the post.

Comment: You don't need to escape >s, so &gt; is not required.