# Finding unescaped html tags in Stack Overflow posts

Tags: discussion, markdown, editing-help

I've been looking at "hidden messages" in posts lately, where the question appears to read, for instance

> Should I use or ?

and the real question becomes visible only when editing:

```
Should I use <span> or <div>?
```

Of course it's not difficult to add backticks to this line manually, but when a very long post contains a lot of these, with regular HTML code blocks in between, it is a lot of work.

So I thought I was smart and copied the message source into my text editor and write a little regex to replace them all, but that's when the troubles started.

I mean, `` ^(<|[^ ].*[^`]<| [^ ].*[^`]<|  [^ ].*[^`]<|   [^ ].*[^`]<)[a-zA-Z/] `` is not good enough!
It gives false positives for indented code blocks in quote blocks, like this

```
>     <div>some html</div>
```

And it gives false negatives for where people are trying to indent a code block, but omit a blank line above:

```
My HTML looks like this:
    <div>some html</div>
```

So, can anybody come up with a better regex? Or some other way of identifying the html that should appear as a code block within the post?

Comment: *Will...... not..... link..... t*... http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/444991... Sorry, I just couldn't stop myself.

Comment: I don't even have to click that link, I know what it says.

Comment: Saw a bunch of regex and other programming looking stuff and was about to flag as off-topic.  Then I looked a second time and realized that this question is about using those to identify problem posts for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also, there's a subset of HTML which is perfectly fine to use in posts. A related FR I posted: [Please block posts containing unsupported HTML](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300679/please-block-posts-containing-unsupported-html) Huh, you already know that one ;-)

Comment: The SOUP userscript claims to already do this.  See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/305526/331508) and [here](http://stackapps.com/q/4486/7653).

Comment: If you don't mind pulling the contents of the posts, you could run them through [HTML Tidy](https://infohound.net/tidy/)

Comment: @Matt I'm still wanting the typo in that answer to be fixed...