# Strings between angular brackets not displayed

Tags: support, markdown-rendering

`*String response = "<I:BARCO@noiclt22815||K:CMS||O:REgetPerspectiveList||A0:googleP||A1:yahooP||A2:gmail||A3:test||>";*`

When I put the above string in italics in one of my posts most of the code isn't displayed:

*String response = "";*

I removed the "<" from the response and then everything works as expected. Is "<" treated as a special character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

In a nutshell, angle brackets < and > (but really more >) are regarded as HTML markup, so you must either escape them or place them inside of a `<code>` block.

There are limits to what HTML can be placed in an answer, but by and large, if you're representing code, you should look to place that between backticks (`).

With backticks, your variable would be:  `String response = "<I:BARCO@noiclt22815||K:CMS||O:REgetPerspectiveList||A0:googleP||A1:yahooP||A2:gmail||A3:test||>";`, which renders correctly every time.

Comment: Relevant: [Please block posts containing unsupported HTML](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300679/please-block-posts-containing-unsupported-html)