# Some source code not showing at all when not formatted correctly

Tags: bug, code-formatting

I came across a question where some of the HTML was missing in the question, and the OP had posted it in a comment underneath, so I took it upon myself to edit this code into the question.

However, when I went to edit the question, that code was already there! Just, not visible at all outside of edit, because it wasn't indented enough.

I appreciate that we should fix these cases when we come across them: applying formatting when needed, but it seems wrong that some code would actually just not render at all - a lazy answerer who would provide an answer but no edit could potentially provide an incorrect answer based on incomplete information.

Compare the rendered output / markdown on the [edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19744148).

Comment: Shouldn’t this be a [tag:feature-request] then?

Comment: How would you expect it to render, instead?

Comment: @Xufox It struck me as a bug with how it rendered, but I guess there are arguments for it being a feature-request.

Comment: Cross-site dupe: [Why are HTML tags silently ignored?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85886/289905).

Comment: @Cerbrus As standard words underneath the code block, like I've seen other times code has not been correctly formatted

Comment: @Cerbrus Or atleast an indication that `something here was stripped out automatically` - silently removing it makes it easy to miss for both the asker and answerer

Comment: @Scoots: A indication like that would make quite a few posts quite messy, I imagine.

Comment: Related: [Please block posts containing unsupported HTML](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300679/4642212).

Comment: @Cerbrus I take your point that it wouldn't be pretty, but one could argue that by missing half their code, they're already messy, and attracting equally messy answers.

Comment: @Scoots: My point is that adding a indication like that will break existing posts.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow only allows a [very strict subset](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) of HTML to be rendered in a question / answer. Any HTML tags that aren't in that subset will be stripped from the (rendered) post, unless you properly indent your code to format it as code.