# Display of Suggested Edit hides important information

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues, suggested-edits

Today when reviewing some suggested edits, I stumbled upon an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19752945) looking like:

[image: rendered output]

At first I was confused, because it looks like the editor tried to add information, some HTML, that maybe would conflict with the authors intents, which would result in a *Reject* of that edit.

But when looking at the comment the editor gave to his edit, saying something like:

> Code should be in gray box

I was again, even more confused. Because there was no gray area in the original question in the *rendered output*. So I looked at the *markdown* of the question and saw following:

[image: markdown]

which clearly shows, that the original question contained that HTML text in the first place.

**My Question now is**: Is this a Bug in the display of the rendered output, or an intended behaviour?

Comment: I think the preview got confused because the user who made the edit moved the last paragraph to the top. Checking the markdown is the right thing to do so kudos for that. I'm not sure if this qualifies as a bug, nor if this can be fixed if it is.

Comment: I posted this, because someone (even myself) may be too lazy, or just too unconcentrated to check the markdown and just reject that edit, which would lead to an useful edit getting lost. So it would probably be better if that would be fixed. But it's as you said not really a Bug

Comment: Well in such cases one should take a break from reviewing :) You might just trip over an audit

Comment: That's the whole purpose of the `markdown` button!

Comment: It's working as intended, but it has tripped up reviewers before. The moral is, always check the markdown for XML and HTML that wasn't displayed properly before. You did a good job double-checking!

Comment: And if you're still feeling confused after looking at the markdown, look at the raw source.

Comment: Related feature request: [Please block posts containing unsupported HTML](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300679/please-block-posts-containing-unsupported-html)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This doesn't qualify as a bug. The "side-by-side" section just shows what the content in the question looks like before and after applying the edit. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50384815/1) is the first revision.

[image]

Since the code was not formatted correctly, the html content was parsed and not taken as code block.

The only way to check the code data is to see the markdown content as you did.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, and answers my question :)

Comment: I tend to review edits with the markdown diff by default, *precisely* because of cases where the edit fixes some formatting issue that causes a large change in the rendered output. Fortunately, raw markdown is fairly pleasant to read most of the time.

Comment: This is a case where it would be good to show the markdown by default. That already happens in some cases (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142919/349538), but obviously not in this case.